# open source alternatives to Hazelcast?

Tags: java, c++, c, scalability, hazelcast

Since the support of native C/C++ clients by Hazecast is still under the ToDo List,
are there any open source alternatives to Hazelcast that supports native C/C++ clients?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use memcache API to access to Hazelcast. So grab any memcache C/C++ client and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which parts of Hazelcast you need. For simple distributed, redundant Maps you could have a look at http://redis.io/clients.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very handy lib - [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It provides distributed Java objects and services (`BitSet`, `BloomFilter`, `Set`, `SortedSet`, `Map`, `ConcurrentMap`, `List`, `Queue`, `Deque`, `BlockingQueue`, `BlockingDeque`, `ReadWriteLock`, `Semaphore`, `Lock`, `AtomicLong`, `CountDownLatch`, `Publish / Subscribe`, `RemoteService`, `ExecutorService`, `LiveObjectService`, `ScheduledExecutorService`) on top of Redis server!

It supports cluster, sentinel, master/slave and single connection modes.

Perfectly works in cloud and supports AWS Elasticache and Azure Redis Cloud

Below are some success stories from Redisson customers:

[Moving from Hazelcast to Redis](https://engineering.datorama.com/moving-from-hazelcast-to-redis-b90a0769d1cb)
[Distributed Locking with Redis (Migration from Hazelcast)](https://carlosbecker.com/posts/distributed-locks-redis/)